# Can't detect month "Jan" in excel table?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

[image]

The reference no, e.g. EPS-I-S160201 is in the format of `EPS-I-"Category""yy""mm""Sequence No"`

Reference No is auto generated to run in sequence. The last 2 digits will auto reset the last 2 numbers back to 01 again, every time when a new month/year is detected under the "Invoice Date" column.

There is a bug in the formula, which the reference no cannot detect any input "Invoice Date" which contains Jan 16. But it can detect Jan 17 later along the rows. Seem that my formula can't recognise Jan on the 1st line of entry. Any options to resolve this?

My formula used is:

> =IF(ISBLANK(C6), "", "EPS-I-"&VLOOKUP(E6, DataBase!$F$3:$G$9, 2, FALSE)&TEXT(C6, "yy")&TEXT(C6, "mm")&TEXT(IF(MONTH(C6)=MONTH(C5), VALUE(RIGHT(B5, 2))+1, 1), "00"))

[image]

Comment: It seems that date in the first two rows is stored as text. Or categories contain extra (non visible) characters, the formula is ok, check the input.

Comment: Remember if posts are useful do upvote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is nothing to do with it being Jan 16, your problem is the last part of the function:

```
TEXT(IF(MONTH(C6)=MONTH(C5),VALUE(RIGHT(B5,2))+1,1) ,"00")
```

It's trying to compare C6 to a month of C5. Well, month of C5 doesn't exist, so it can't compare it.

So, the next line is comparing C7 to C6. That's fine, it can do that, it's true. Except, now you're trying to check the value of B5, which, because of the last bit, can't be done.

The next lines are fine because they're no longer in the same month, so the sequence starts afresh with valid values.

You've basically just got a cascading error because of the first failure.

So let's prevent that first error happening:

```
TEXT(IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(C5)),(MONTH(C6)=MONTH(C5))),VALUE(RIGHT(B5,2))+1,1),"00"))
```

To be honest, you should do more checks than this, but you need to amend something like this (Untested, but should put you on the right path)

Comment: thanks for your kind advise and solution. It works great. I am working hard to pick up all these formulas bits and pieces...lol Merry Christmas to you and you guys out there. Thanks for all your great help. Cheers....

Comment: Not a problem. For future reference, I believe questions about Excel formulas should be directed to [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-formula), this site is more aimed at general software issues. :)

Comment: Sorry didnt notice about this earlier, will take note in future...lol

Comment: @Jonno Excel formula questions **are** on topic at SU.

Comment: @DavidPostill Okay my mistake - sorry for the misleading information - carry on as you were Brandon!

Answer (score 1):

@Jonno has it right.  Basically, you have an issue with your formula.

It works by checking the month in the previous row.  There is no month in the previous row to row 6.  Therefore it doesn't have a month to compare to.

You need to either change the formula for the first row, or add dummy data giving you a) a month, and b) a sequence in row 5.  Without both of these, the first row of your formula won't ever work.